# Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented THEN Property 'self.album' not initialized at super.init call THEN Assigning a property to itself

Tags: swift, uikit

so I am creating an app that includes an audio player that is accessed through a button called   from the main page once the user has logged into their account. All of the pages of the app have been created using Storyboards but the audio player is done programmatically with SwiftUI. The app runs fine until you press the  button to access the audio player. Then I get "Thread 1: Fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented" on the AudioPlayerViewController. So I searched for a solution online and as per the suggestions here, on stackOverflow, removed this:

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

And put this, instead, as suggested:

```
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

But then I get this error:

"Property 'self.album' not initialized at super.init call"

so I add: " self.album = album" - as you see below:

```
 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.album = album

}
```

But then I get the error: "Assigning a property to itself"

And now I'm tired. Send help.

Let me know if I should share a link to my code or whatever else, I haven't asked a question here before.

I guess here's the whole code anyway:

```
import UIKit

final class AudioPlayerViewController: UIViewController {
var album: Album

private lazy var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer = {
    let v = MediaPlayer(album: album)
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return v
}()

init(album: Album) {
    self.album = album
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}

//    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
//        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been     implemented")
//    }

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.album = album

}
//    override func awakeFromNib() {
//       super.awakeFromNib()
//       //custom logic goes here
//    }
//
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupView()
}

private func setupView() {
    addBlurredView()
    view.addSubview(mediaPlayer)
    
    setupConstraints()
}

private func addBlurredView() {
    if !UIAccessibility.isReduceTransparencyEnabled {
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.dark)
        let blueEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blueEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
        blueEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        
        view.addSubview(blueEffectView)
    } else {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }
}

private func setupConstraints() {
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        mediaPlayer.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
        mediaPlayer.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        mediaPlayer.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        mediaPlayer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
    ])
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    mediaPlayer.play()
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    mediaPlayer.stop()
    UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = false
}
}
```

Comment: You could make `album` an Optional.

Comment: This isn't SwiftUI

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! This answer will not solve all your problems, but it addresses your question. You should feel free to ask (open/submit)  additional questions once you get over this speed bump.

When the compiler complained that:

"Property 'self.album' not initialized at super.init call"

You say you added:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.album = album

}
```

But that doesn't address what the compiler just complained about:

**The property `self.album` is still not initialized at super.init call.**

You just added it in the wrong place is all.
Initialize self.album before calling super:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   self.album = album
   super.init(coder: aDecoder) 
}
```

The following is from Apple's online documentation
[AppleDoc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html)

> Two-Phase Initialization
> Class initialization in Swift is a two-phase process. In the first phase, each stored property is assigned an initial value by the class that introduced it. Once the initial state for every stored property has been determined, the second phase begins, and each class is given the opportunity to customize its stored properties further before the new instance is considered ready for use.

> The use of a two-phase initialization process makes initialization safe, while still giving complete flexibility to each class in a class hierarchy. Two-phase initialization prevents property values from being accessed before they’re initialized, and prevents property values from being set to a different value by another initializer unexpectedly.